# Fastest way to assign value to pandas cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function called `calculate_distance`, which takes 4 Pandas cells as an input and returns a new value that I want to assign it to a specific Pandas cell.
The 4 input values change dynamically as seen in the code below.

```
df['distance'] = ''
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
   df.at[i, 'distance'] = calculate_distance(df['latitude'].iloc[i-1], df['longitude'].iloc[i-1], df['latitude'].iloc[i], df['longitude'].iloc[i])
```

Is there a faster way to do it than this "newbie" for loop?

Comment: You can check https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance, where (a bit down in the page) something similar is done (distance between two latitude/longitude pairs); a solution might be to first add new columns "prev_latitude"/"prev_longitude" (as a shift of the existing latitude/longitude) and then copy (or modify) the linked solution.

Comment: Generally speaking, the efficient thing is to do is to write code that takes columns as input and takes advantage of vectorised methods, and if possible to avoid explicit loops or using .apply() too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(your_calculate_distance_def, axis=1)
```

Its faster than loop. I dont know what your definition does. But apply will help you boost speed.

You may refer to Pandas apply documentation here for more help - [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)